# XML parser python fails to get element

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

etree.ElementTree package in python to parse my xml file but it seems it fails to do so.

My xml file hierarchy is like this:
    root
  <-       ->
config     data
            <>
            sourcefile
           <-  ->
          file  object1 object2 ... etc.

when I use print self.xml_root.findall(".\config"), I only got "[]", which is an empty list,
thanks

Comment: can you please give a sample of your xml file and the code you used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really have `'.\config'` in the string, that would be the problem.  That's a string literal using `\c` as one of its characters.  Even if you have `'.\\config'` or `r'.\config'`, both of which specify a literal backslash, that would still be wrong:

```
$ cat eleme.py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

root = ET.fromstring("""
<root>
  <config>
    source
  </config>
  <config>
    source
  </config>
</root>""")

print r'using .\config', root.findall('.\config')
print r'using .\\config', root.findall('.\\config')
print 'using ./config', root.findall('./config')
$ python2.7 eleme.py 
using .\config []
using .\\config []
using ./config [<Element 'config' at 0x8017a8610>, <Element 'config' at 0x8017a8650>]
```

Comment: so I need './config'?, but the actual situation is that I cannot use root.iter('object'), which is a grand-child node of root. What's the problem with that? Thank you

Comment: I'll need to see more actual code and XML to know what you mean here.  In general `elem.iter()`, for any element, gives you an iterator over the item and its children: basically, `yield self` followed by `yield next_child_in_sequence', optionally restricting by tag-match.